# npm init will not create package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-init

test directory is empty and running npm init doesn't create a package.json file.

error below says there's no such directory which is confusing as I'm in said directory when running npm init command.

```
PS C:\Users\Sayee\OneDrive\Documents\test> npm init

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (test)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Users\Sayee\OneDrive\Documents\test\package.json:

{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Is this OK? (yes)
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sayee\OneDrive\Documents\test\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Sayee\OneDrive\Documents\test\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sayee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-01T19_50_44_400Z-debug.log
```

Versions:

- node v15.5.1
- npm v7.4.2

**edit:**

different error if I manually create an empty package.json file in the directory. Package.json file is not open anywhere and I've tried running terminal as admin.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'write'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sayee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-01T23_57_39_015Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If you create an empty package.json, does it do the same ?

Comment: yes, I have tried that and I get a different error. errno: -4048. Operation rejected because the file was already in use or lack permission to access it. I'm running a terminal as admin and package.json is not open anywhere as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue has nothing to do with npm/node, and it might be due to the special filesystem ownership/permission of `C:\Users\Sayee\OneDrive\Documents\`.

Comment: You're correct. I tried npm init outside of the OneDrive directory and it worked fine. Turns out the 'controlled folder access' feature on windows was the issue so disabling that was the solution.

Comment: @SyM that doesn't sound like a viable solution, have a look at symlinks [example here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/can-t-synchronize-onedrive-files-and-folders-from-a-local-file-location-other-than-the-default-onedrive-path-b7eef9d4-4203-431d-8345-fe49254f9da0) this is a better approach. I've tried it some time ago with OneDrive for syncing a "saves" folder from a game between workpc-homepc and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling **Controlled folder access** in windows under Ransomeware Protection fixed the issue.